# XMPP Room Join/Create Response Code on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework, prosody-im

I am trying to create a new room via [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework). I send the presence like this.

```
<presence
    from='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'
    to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit/firstwitch'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
</presence>
```

[XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) is expecting the response code to be **201**. But I am getting **110** in response!

```
<presence
    from='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit/firstwitch'
    to='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'>
    <item affiliation='owner'
          role='moderator'/>
    <status code='110'/>
  </x>
</presence>
```

But when I look at the official specification, it expect the get back both codes. Totally confusing me right now.

```
<presence
    from='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit/firstwitch'
    to='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'>
    <item affiliation='owner'
          role='moderator'/>
    <status code='110'/>
    <status code='201'/>
  </x>
</presence>
```

Answer (score 0):

My team is using Prosody-im version `0.9.7` and it seems the issue exist in this particular build. Attached is the chat discussion which I had in their conference room.

[image]